# how do I create a functioning vector<wchar_t> that has an erase(size_t pos) method?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, wchar-t

I am creating a C++ `wstring` class for use with mingw version 4.3.0, cross-compiling for Win32. I want my string to work like `std::string` which means that I want an `erase(int pos)` method that erases a single element at position `pos`.

Here is my first attempt:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class wstring : public std::vector<wchar_t>{
public:
    void erase(size_t where){
    erase(begin()+where);
    }
};

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    wstring c1;
    c1.push_back(L'a');
    c1.push_back(L'b');
    c1.push_back(L'c');
    c1.erase(1);

    for(size_t i = 0;i<c1.size();i++){
    std::cout << "c1[" << i << "] = " << c1[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This looks like it should work to me, but I get this wacko compiler error when I try to compile it:

```
$ i386-mingw32-g++ x1.cpp
x1.cpp: In member function 'void wstring::erase(size_t)':
x1.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to 'wstring::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t*, std::vector<wchar_t, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >)'
x1.cpp:7: note: candidates are: void wstring::erase(size_t)
$
```

What's really weird is that if I take out the `erase` method and just inline the code, I have no problem:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class wstring : public std::vector<wchar_t>{
};

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    wstring c1;
    c1.push_back(L'a');
    c1.push_back(L'b');
    c1.push_back(L'c');
    c1.erase(c1.begin()+1);

    for(size_t i = 0;i<c1.size();i++){
    std::cout << "c1[" << i << "] = " << c1[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm mystified.

Comment: I thought you called your method `remove` -- why isn't it `c1.remove(1)`?

Comment: Oh, also don't derive from standard library containers! And is there a reason you can't use `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`?

Comment: I fixed the demo program. My method is supposed to be called erase(), as I'm trying to add new erase() method that works like the `std::string` erase and allows you to erase by offset.

Comment: Deriving from std::baseic_string<wchar_t> is an interesting idea.  In fact, that solved my problem!  Why don't you list that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You "fixed" it the wrong way -- now you have `erase` in your class and in the base class! Why not leave it at `remove` as you had it originally and just fix the invocation?

Comment: Seriously, don't derive from standard library types! (There are exceptions, like... exceptions, and iterators, but never from heavy-weight classes.)

Comment: @vy: You should probably accept David's answer if you go with `std::wstring`, since he already said it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your particular question is to use `std::vector<T>::erase( iterator )` instead of `remove`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back( 1 );
v.push_back( 2 );
v.push_back( 3 );
v.erase( v.begin()+1 ); // equivalent to v.remove( 1 )
```

But I don't think that you are barking at the right tree. There is already a `std::wstring` in the standard library that is the instantiation of `basic_string` with `wchar_t`, and that will get as close as it can to `std::string` (which is an instantiation of the same template with `char`)

Comment: +1 for the wrong tree, and if I could +1 again for suggesting std::wstring, I would.

Comment: There is no std::wstring in the mingw STL.

Comment: @vy32:  Are you sure?  It should.  I don't have an older version to test with, but in mingw 4.5.2 there certainly is a `std::wstring` in `<string>`.  If nothing else, are you unable to use `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`?

Comment: Gosh, I'm an idiot. You are right, there is a wstring. It's just not in the #include directory where I was grepping. Sigh.

Comment: Learning the STL by grep-ing in the include directory might not be the best idea. You might consider some short of book or tutorial as a easier path into learning.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just use the existing type `std::wstring`, which is a typedef for `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`. Feel free to make other string classes based on your favourite integral types, too.

Note that there are corresponding stream objects `std::wcout` etc.

Comment: @vy: To be fair, this is the same suggestion that David made, so you might as well make his answer the accepted one... :-)

Comment: Indeed. I guess that's why David has 34.7k.